# How can I speed up rendering an animation with Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I started to render an animation (of 200 frames), using 1000 samples, at 1920x1080 pixels, of a scene including a fog object and mesh files  (from Alias).
It took almost 10 hours for 1 frame, so I think that something is wrong. Is this a usual amount of render time?

I want to keep the quality as high as possible.

I'm using Cycles rendering with CPU, because when I try to use GPU, Blender shuts down.

Specs:
AMD Ryzen 5 3600- 6 core processor
16 Gb RAM
GTX 1660 SUPER

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your scene and the precise render settings you’re using, it is certainly *possible* for a single frame to take 10 hours to render. (A brief internet search suggests a single frame in a Pixar film can take even longer than that during particularly resource-heavy sequences.) It’s hard to say whether or not anything abnormal is happening without more information—perhaps you can [upload your .blend file?](https://pasteall.org/blend/)

Comment: my blender file is too big to upload here, my file is almost 1.8 GB..

Comment: With a file of that size, it's not too surprising that rendering one frame is going to take that long!

Comment: I uploaded my ifle , as you said , , it's not too surprising..! okay got it

Comment: File size alone cannot account for the long rendering time. Fog objects are hard to render (try removing the fog object and see how much time it shaves off), and I think it would be wise to figure out why you cannot use your GPU. Your Nvidia card has CUDA support. Have you tried installing the latest drivers for it?

Comment: Yes I updated my graphic card.. I'm trying to find what is the problem with my GPU

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend you use the GPU. Blender probably shuts down because you didn't set it to use the GPU at the preferences tab. Go to Edit > Preferences > System > Set it to the GPU you use, NVIDIA is CUDA, AMD is OpenGl. Other things you can do is optimize the amount of bounces in Render Properties > Light Paths > Max Bounces.

[image: Where to find light paths]

Comment: The OP mentions that if they use GPU Blender crashes.

Comment: I am aware @Joachim , which I why I asked him to try to set up the settings at the start.